# In calendar control renderEvent is not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

In calendar control after inserting data, I call renderEvent to get recently inserted data. But I have found undefied.
#when i refresh browser I get that data but using render I didn't get data.

**Here is my code.**

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Admin/Calendar/SaveBookings",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: { title, Description, startDate, EndDate },
  success: function (response) {
    debugger;
    $("#bookingModal").modal("hide");
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", {
      title: response.title,
      description: response.description,
      start: response.startDate,
      end: response.endDate,
    });
  },
  error: function (error) {
    if (error.responseJSON.errors) {
      $("#titleError").html(error.responseJSON.errors.title);
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: `But I have found undefied`...we have no idea what this really means. If you have an error, please [edit] your question to show the exact, full error message (with no abbreviations or paraphrasing, please) and point out to us the line of code which the error message said it occurred on (remember we can't see your line numbers).

Answer (score -1):

Here you need to make some changes in **FullCalendar**.

- **successCallback** we need to create `eventsArray` we will push when we want to update the calendar.

```js
events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    successCallback(eventsArray);
}
```

- Push new events to calendar using `eventsArray.push(eventData);`
- Refresh calendar with `calendar.refetchEvents();`

#### Try below Snippet

```js
var eventsArray = [];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        height: 600,
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'interaction'],

        eventClick: function (info) {
            alert(info.event.title)
        },
        events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            successCallback(eventsArray);
        }
    });

    calendar.render();
    var eventData = {
        title: 'New Event',
        start: '2023-04-25T14:00:00',
        end: '2023-04-26T16:00:00'
    };
    eventsArray.push(eventData);
    calendar.refetchEvents();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.2.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.2.0/main.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="calendar"></div>
```